# file streaming to object store through ibm-cos-sdk

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

I have seen the sample code in the site https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-cos-sdk :

```
function doCreateObject() {
    console.log('Creating object');
    return cos.putObject({
        Bucket: 'my-bucket',
        Key: 'foo',
        Body: 'bar'
    }).promise();
}
```

Is it possible to supply stream as a body (e.g. file being uploaded) instead of supplying the entire body as once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream('/Users/paulcarron/Desktop/image.jpeg');

function doCreateObject() {
  console.log('Creating object');
  return cos.putObject({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: 'foo.jpg',
    Body: stream
  }).promise();
}
```